# Can an element have both id and attribute at the same time?

Tags: xml, database, dtd

I know that the question is probably trivial, but I really need to know this stuff.

Here's an example of what I precisely mean:

XML Code:

```
<product id="01" quantity="4 peaces"> Chocolate Cake </product>
```

Also, what would be in this case the attribute-type declaration in the DTD-file?
Perhaps 'CDATA'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example shows an element with two attributes: `id` and `quantity`.  XML does not limit the number of attributes an element can have, so, ***yes, an element can have both an `id` (attribute) and other attributes at the same time*.**

### DTD declarations:

```
<!ELEMENT product (#PCDATA)>
<!ATTLIST product 
          id ID #REQUIRED
          quantity CDATA #REQUIRED>
```

Or, if you must accommodate `id` values that begin with a digit, which as Daniel Haley rightly [points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41921897/can-an-element-have-both-id-and-attribute-at-the-same-time/41928098?noredirect=1#comment71148858_41928098) are not allowed by `ID`, you could use `CDATA` for `id`.

Comment: +1, but it would be worth noting that the value of the `id` attribute in the OP's example would be invalid if the [attribute type](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-attribute-types) `ID` is used in the DTD (IDs can't start with a digit).

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion yes, it can have both. The id is just an attribute like quantity and every xml-element can have `n` attributes. So it should work.

But I can not help you with your second question. I have never used DTD-files.
Maybe this converter can help you: http://bsp.mits.ch/xsd2dtd/